# SQL statement not returning anything or returning NULL in some fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join, inner-join

I've looked at quite a few questions on here and other sites and still cannot see why my SQL statement is returning nothing.

Basically I've got a database called 'takeaway' split into two tables `categories` and `menuitems`.

I want to output each category name `catname` and the menu items associated with each category for example `Cod Fillet` is part of category 2 'catid'.

Categories Table Fields:

```
catid
catname
```

Menuitems Table Fields:

```
itemid
itemname
itemsize
itemprice
categoryid (foreign key)
```

I've used the following SQL statement but is producing nothing

```
select
    menuitems.itemname,
    menuitems.size,
    menuitems.price,
    menuitems.categoryid,
    categories.catid,
    categories.catname 
FROM categories 
RIGHT JOIN menuitems
    ON categories.catid=menuitems.categoryid
```

I've tried an INNER JOIN and  LEFT JOIN. Nothing has worked. I want to output like so:

```
Fish
    - Cod Fillet Large: £4.90 Medium: £3.90
```

And so on... obviously I'm doing this using Mysql and PHP.

Please can someone help point out where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Dan

Comment: `Nothing has worked` ... what isn't working?  Your query looks like it should be returning something.

Comment: You should use INNER JOIN here, not RIGHT JOIN. Your query should definitely return some data, unless you're lacking matches on the columns `categories.catid = menuitems.categoryid` (which I would guess is the case, since you get NULL on RIGHT JOIN).

Comment: Changing it to INNER JOIN produces no results. There are 11 categories and there is at least one item in each category so I really do not understand why there are no results.

Comment: @Daniel Can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
    menuitems.itemname,
    menuitems.itemsize,
    menuitems.itemprice,
    menuitems.categoryid,
    categories.catid,
    categories.catname
FROM categories AS  categories
Left JOIN menuitems AS menuitems
    ON categories.catid = menuitems.categoryid;
```

Comment: Tried that statement and that produced an error message from PHPMyAdmin: #1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Comment: put parentheses   ON (categories.catid = menuitems.categoryid);

Comment: Thanks that worked! Thanks to anyone else who helped.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out the following queries...and you can check the result in below link...Hope it will help you..

I've created tables as requirements...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/082891/2

```
select
    Menuitems.itemname,
    Menuitems.itemsize,
    Menuitems.itemprice,
    Menuitems.categoryid,
    Categories.catid,
    Categories.catname
FROM Categories 
Left JOIN Menuitems 
    ON Categories.catid = Menuitems.categoryid;
```

From this result you can customise your need...

Comment: Thank you again. That helps a lot.